# Xamarinで作成したexeファイルを、Mono同梱でMacアプリとして配布する方法

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin

C＃で作成されたWindowsアプリケーションを、Xamarinを使ってMacアプリに変換したいと考えています。
Xamarin StudioをインストールしたMacで、Windowsアプリケーションのソリューションを開き、
ビルドするとexeが作成され、Mono上で動作することは確認できました。
このexeを、Macアプリケーションとして配布する場合、
Monoのランタイムを同梱してインストーラを作成するような機能は、Xamarinにあるのでしょうか？
また、実行する際、ターミナルから実行するしかないのでしょうか？
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monoランタイムを同梱したインストーラの作成機能は提供されていません。
MacアプリにおけるXamarinは，アプリケーションバンドル（.app）内にランタイムを同梱し，単体で動作するようにビルドする仕組みを提供しています。
これを行いたい場合はXamarin.Mac プロジェクトを作成し，多少コードの移植を行う必要があります。
ご質問の状況ではWindowsのソリューションをそのままビルドされているため，別途ランタイムのインストール無しに動作させる方法はありません。

ターミナルから実行したくない場合は，

1. ブートストラップを含んだバンドルを作成する
2. シェルスクリプトで呼び出す

といった方法があります。バンドルを作成するには `mkbundle` ツールを使います。少し古いですが参考までに。
http://www.mono-project.com/archived/guiderunning_mono_applications/
http://qiita.com/ailen0ada/items/8f1a440c5d620a53c02e
Monoランタイムのライセンスには十分注意なさってください。